# Angular2 - Defining/Injecting Singleton

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives

I have an alert directive defined, like so:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import { Alert } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'alert_directive',
  templateUrl: './shared/directives/alert/alert.html',
  directives: [Alert, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AlertDirective {
  alerts:Array<Object> = [ ];

  closeAlert(i:number) {
    this.alerts.splice(i, 1);
  }

  addAlert(message: string, style: string) {
    this.alerts.push({msg: message, type: style, closable: true});
    console.log(this.alerts);
  }
}
```

I then define my `app` component where I include this directive:

```
import {AlertDirective} from '../../shared/directives/alert/alert';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app/components/app.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/components/app.css'],
  providers: [UserService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, AlertDirective]
})
...
```

This all works, and the directive shows up in the DOM related to my `app.html` file.

This `app.html` file contains some global html (navbar, footer, alert_directive). I want `alert_directive` to be a singleton which I can change the `alerts` array on to show alert messages from any view without having to add the directive to each view.

So, in another `sign in` component:

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/core';
import {AlertDirective} from '../../shared/directives/alert/alert';
@Component({
  selector: 'sign_in',
  templateUrl: './sign_in/components/sign_in.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign_in/components/sign_in.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class SignInCmp {
  alertDirective: AlertDirective;
  constructor(alertDirective: AlertDirective) {
    this.alertDirective = alertDirective;
  }

  showAlert() {
    this.alertDirective.addAlert('test', 'warning');
  }
}
```

The issue here is I am `newing` up a new instance of `AlertDirective`, and therefore my `addAlert` method is adding to the array of my new instance, not the existing instance which is defined in my `app` component.

How can I create a directive as a singleton and inject the one single instance into each view, where I can then call any method on that singleton and affect each injected instance?

Comment: I guess a better way is using service, rather than making that component singleton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a shared service  (only registered in `bootstrap()`) and use it to communicate between components and your `AlertDirective` like showb in [How do i share data between components in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular2)
The service can also contain an `EventEmitter` so all participants can subscribe passed messages.

```
@Injectable()
export class AlertService {
  command: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'alert_directive',
  templateUrl: './shared/directives/alert/alert.html',
  directives: [Alert, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AlertDirective {
  constructor(private alertService: AlertService) {
    alertService.commands.subscribe((command) => { doSomething();}
  }
  alerts:Array<Object> = [ ];

  closeAlert(i:number) {
    this.alerts.splice(i, 1);
  }

  addAlert(message: string, style: string) {
    this.alerts.push({msg: message, type: style, closable: true});
    console.log(this.alerts);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'sign_in',
  templateUrl: './sign_in/components/sign_in.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign_in/components/sign_in.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class SignInCmp {
  alertDirective: AlertDirective;
  constructor(alertService: AlertService) {
    this.alertService = alertService;
  }

  showAlert() {
    this.sharedService.command.next({text: 'test', title: 'warning'});
  }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [/* other providers */, AlertService]);
```