# Share object between 2 child components

Tags: angular

I have a main component with 3 sub-components.

Main component HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <reserved-parking></reserved-parking>

      <available-parking></available-parking>

      <profile></profile>
   </div>
</div>
```

For instance, when a user selects parking from available-parking component information should be sent to reserved-parking component. So, I need to pass a JSON object from available-parking to reserved-parking component.

I've tried to use `@Input`, but no luck. Only from parent to child and vice-versa.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use event emitters and **two-way** binding like this.

**parent component**

```ts
@Component(){
...
}
export class ParentComp{
  parkingLots: Array<any> =  [one,two,three];
  constructor(){}
}
```

**parent template**

```ts
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <reserved-parking [(data)]="parkingLots"></reserved-parking>

      <available-parking [(data)]="parkingLots"></available-parking>

      <profile></profile>
   </div>
</div>
```

**reserved-parking component**

```ts
@Component(){
selector: 'reserved-parking',
inputs: ['data'],
outputs: ['dataChange'],
...
}
export class ReservedParking{
  data: Array<any>;
  dataChange: EventEmitter<Array<any>> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.push('four');
    this.dataChange.emit(this.data);
  }
}
```

**available-parking component**

```ts
@Component(){
selector: 'available-parking',
inputs: ['data'],
outputs: ['dataChange'],
...
}
export class AvailableParking{
  data: Array<any>;
  dataChange: EventEmitter<Array<any>> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data);
   // you can also update it here and then do      
   // this.dataChange.emit(this.data); to send it out
  }
}
```

---

**note:** import anything required, data is arbitrary change it according to your needs, main thing is to emit the value after modification by doing `dataChange.emit(this.data)`

Comment: You only posted a template - now it's more clear! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :-)

Comment: @rinukkusu , AH that , I was just applying the SO rules, answer first - modify later ;)

Answer (score 3):

`@Input API` can be used when you have **parent-child** scenario and sending data from parent to child. But here, you are having sibling components. `EventEmitter` can be used but over the time it becomes complex. 
I'd suggest to use `sharedService` with `subject` from `Rxjs library`.

***NOTE***: **Please bear with Naming Convention for this example.**

https://plnkr.co/edit/7A21ofKNdi0uvbMgLUDZ?p=preview

**sharedService.ts (with subject)**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class sharedService {

    private parkingType = new Subject<string[]>();
    parkingType$ = this.parkingType.asObservable();

    ParkingType(jsonData){
     console.log(jsonData);
      this.parkingType.next(jsonData);
    }

}
```

**availableParking.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {sharedService} from 'src/sharedService';

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  template: `
   <h1> Available parking </h1>
   <button (click)="send()">Send Json Object</button>
  `
})
export class availableParking{
  myjson=[{"parkingType":"free parking"},{"parkingType":"paid parking"}];
  constructor(private ss: sharedService) {}

  send()
  {
     console.log(this.myjson);
    this.ss.ParkingType(this.myjson);
  }
}
```

**reservedParking.ts**

```
import {Component,Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {sharedService} from 'src/sharedService';
import {someService} from 'src/someService';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
@Component({
  selector: 'thecontent',
    template: `
    <h1>Reserved parking</h1>
    {{myjson|json}}
    `
})
export class reservedParking{
  myjson:string[];
  constructor(private ss: sharedService) {
    ss.parkingType$.subscribe((res)=>this.myjson=res); 
  }
}
```