# Two way data binding for object between components

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I have component with input:

```
<my-input *ngIf='filter.type === checkType.INPUT_TEXT' [filter]='filter'></my-input>

export class MyInputComponent{
  @Input() filter: any;
}
```

Template of MyInputComponent

```
<input name="name" [(ngModel)]="filter.input">
```

I want to set filter input inside  and have influence on outer Component object.

**How to pass filter object into `MyInputComponent` to achieve 2 way data binding?**

I want to achIeve something like [(ngModel)]="filter.value" but working between Components

Other posts here about 2-way data binding does'nt answer my questions.

**Edit:**

After using `extends DefaultValueAccessor` in my MyInputComponent my parent component input disapears without any error.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Provider, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, DefaultValueAccessor } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-input',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  host: { '(keyup)': 'doOnChange($event.target)' },
  templateUrl: '<input name="name" [(ngModel)]="filter.input">'
})

export class MyInputComponent extends DefaultValueAccessor {
  @Input() filter: any;

  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(filter:any):void {
    if (filter !== null) {
      super.writeValue(filter.toString());
    }
  }
  doOnChange(filter) {
    this.onChange(filter);
  }
}

const MY_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyInputComponent), multi: true});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/38097777/652850

Comment: Write some content from link and then support it by link. Links often become invalid and your answer become useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a custom value accessor for this. Here is a sample of this:

```
const MY_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyInputComponent), multi: true});

@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ MY_VALUE_ACCESSOR ]
})
export class MyInputComponent extends DefaultValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(value:any):void {
    if (value!=null) {
      super.writeValue(value.toString());
    }
  }

  // call when your internal input is updated
  doOnChange(val) {
    this.onChange(val);
  }
}
```

For more details, see this article (section "NgModel-compatible component"):

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

See also this question:

- [angular2 wysiwyg tinymce implementation and 2-way-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841335/angular2-wysiwyg-tinymce-implementation-and-2-way-binding/36841485#36841485)

Comment: I will check it, my experience is low so, is this the best way to set value field of object passed like this or better is to go out of all Comonents up in hierarchy and set it by passing index and value by method better practice, or is there any other way to set this value?