# Navigate to tab passing parameter

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Is posibble to pass parameter with this method:

```
this.app.getRootNav().getActiveChildNav().select(3);
```

i tried:

```
this.app.getRootNav().getActiveChildNav().select(3, {apto: 1});
```

but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, according to the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/#select) the `select` function only takes one parameter (`tabOrIndex`) specifying the tab or index to select. A [quick look into the corresponding code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/96945b1ee1d57b9438ed149d07b4a0deea0ee30c/core/src/components/tabs/tabs.tsx#L120) verifies this.

---

To work arround this and pass data from one tab to another you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42713620/5730444) which offers three possible approaches to this problem.