# Pass data between parent level components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have two angular components `SignupComponent` and `SignupSuccessComponent`. I want to pass data from the `SignupComponent` to `SignupSuccessComponent`, currently i have tried using a shared service with no luck.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('signupForm') form: FormData;
  constructor(public router: Router, private userService: UserService, private signupService: SignupService) { }

  onSubmit() {
   //user object is gotten from a network request
   this.router.navigate(['/signup/success']);
   this.signupService.setUser(user);
  }
}
```

The SignupSuccessComponent

```
@Component({
          selector: 'app-signup-success',
          templateUrl: './signup-success.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./signup-success.component.scss']
        })
        export class SignupSuccessComponent implements OnInit {

          public user: User;

          constructor(public router: Router, private signupService: SignupService) { 
          }

          ngOnInit() {
            this.signupService.user$.subscribe(data => {
              this.user = data;
              console.log(this.user);
            })
          }
        }
```

This is the shared service

```
@Injectable()
export class SignupService {

    private user = new Subject<User>();

    user$ = this.user.asObservable();

    setUser(data: User) {
        this.user.next(data);
    }
}
```

It seem as though the shared service never gets any data in SignupSuccessComponent

Comment: Where is the shared service being provided? Are you sure that the same shared service instance is inject in both components?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen The shared service is being provided in a SignupModule

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error?

Comment: @MaKobi the SignupSuccessComponent doesn't get the data i'm trying to pass

Comment: Have you checked whether shared service is getting the data or not ?

Answer (score 2):

I decided to use local storage to pass data between the components.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

    @Injectable()
    export class SignupService {

        constructor(private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {}

        setUser(data) {
            this.localStorageService.set('user.new', data);
        }

        getUser() {
            return this.localStorageService.get('user.new');
        }

        clearUser() {
            this.localStorageService.remove('user.new');
        }
    }
```

I can call `setUser` in the `SignupComponent` and get the data using `getUser` in the `ngOnInit` method of `SignupSuccessComponent`

Comment: It's a bad idea to use local storage to pass data. What if the user disabled the local storage?

Answer (score 0):

In SignupSuccessComponent you receive data in ngOnInit which is executed only once at the beginning of the component lifecycle. So when the submit button fires onSubmit(),  it doesn't change anything in SignupSuccessComponent. To correct, you need to add an @Input with a setter this way:

```
@Input()
  set name(name: string) {
    this._name = (name && name.trim()) || '<no name set>';
  }

  get name(): string { return this._name; }
```

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Answer (score 0):

You can use getUser() method to just return the user object.
I have create a demo for same: github link:https://github.com/sachinkasana/sharedServiceDemo

**//SignupService

```
@Injectable()
export class SignupService {
   // private user = new Subject<User>();
   //I am taking this simple string type for your reference
 private user = "";
   // user$ = this.user.asObservable();
    setUser(data: string) {
        this.user=data;
    }
    getUser(){
        return this.user;
    }
}
```

**

//SignupComponentComponent

```
export class SignupComponentComponent  {
    @ViewChild('signupForm') form: FormData;
  constructor(public router: Router, private signupService: SignupService) { }

  onSubmit() {
   //user object is gotten from a network request
   this.router.navigate(['/signup/success']);
   this.signupService.setUser('Test User From signup');
  }
}
```

//SignupSuccessComponentComponent

```
export class SignupSuccessComponentComponent implements OnInit {
   public user: string;
    constructor(public router: Router, private signupService: SignupService){}
          ngOnInit() {
          this.user= this.signupService.getUser()
              console.log(this.user);
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a solution without using service, but using parent child propagation.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45274521/1033326