# Ionic sending data between child and parent component. Best approach?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement search feature. Looks something like this.
This is my parent component:

[image]

Once you click to Advanced it goes to modalController where you can select different filters:

[image]

I want to filter my search result by those filter by passing object called **data**. Facebook property should be either 1 or 0 and so on.

So for example one toggle is on, set data = { facebook = '1'}

So. I have an object in my parent component **Search.ts**

data = {
      search: ' ',
      facebook: ' '
    };

And I want to update facebook property from childComponent once Facebook Allowed is toggled.

I am not sure what is the best way to do it?

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

When you close modal at that time you pass data to child component like

```
this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.pick_color);
```

Instead of `this.pick_color` you have pass your object of facebook and email allowed.

You have to catch passed value in child component like

```
let colorModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ColorModal, { notes_data_id: notes_data_id });
colorModal.present();

colorModal.onDidDismiss(data=>
{
    console.log(data);   
});
```

For more info

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/passing-data-in-from-modal/61051/2

Comment: Super. Did that. Now I receive the object from child component to parent.
After 
console.log(data) I receive: 
{facebook: "1", email: ""}

Question is : How can I now insert this data to my data object in parent component.
Rookie out here! Thanks

Comment: Now I receive the object from child component to parent. After console.log(data) I receive: {facebook: "1", email: ""} Question is : How can I now insert this data to my data object in parent component. Rookie out here! Thanks

Comment: You can use that object in your child component.

Comment: yeah, but the thing is. I use data object in parent component to send it to the API and by object parameters, it's got the data. So I need somehow to pass facebook parameter value from child component to parent data object. 
Not sure if it makes sense for you.

Comment: You mean facebook allowed, email allowed also dynamic mean they comes from api call?

Comment: No, but I have to pass them as parameter to the api if I user want to see list where facebook or email is allowed.

Comment: Means when onDidDismiss() is called you have to pass facebook and email object to with api call right?

Comment: Yes.  I pass  data variable to api from my Search.ts (parent component)

  data = {
      category: ' ',
      search: ' ',
      facebook: ' ',
      email: ' '
    };

Comment: For that you have use event and publish

Comment: Thanks! 
Could you help me with where should i start?

Comment: Please refer given link for events and publish for ionic 3. If i helps you please dont forgot accept and upvote to answer