# Angular4 : Share an object between application components

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in Angular 4 developement with typescript :
I want to create a reusable static object in `app.component.ts` 
and get its value in all components 
How can I do this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share values or method between components, you need to create a `service`, for example, a `user.service.ts` that share the currently logged in user and spread his infos in the components where it is injected.

Here's the official documentation about angular services : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4