# Two way data bining between components

Tags: angular

I have 2 components: MenuComponent and HeaderComponent.
In my HeaderComponent I have a select and when customer choose an option I need to show/hide a div element in MenuComponent.

Is there an example that can help me?

Here is my code:

header.component.html

```
 <div class="select-style">
        <select>
          <option value="" disabled selected> Role </option>
          <option value="admin">Administrator</option>
          <option value="user">Employee</option>
        </select>
  </div>
```

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,  EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ca-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try and find other posts, there are plenty of questions here on SO regarding this. Here are two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884451/angular-2-sibling-component-communication and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular-2

Comment: I think its easier to create service and use it to share state across these component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can resolve this, first one and maybe the best is creating a shared service that will be injected into your root module which is probably `app.module.ts` and then inject it inside of your components. Second solution is if your `menu component` contains `header component` inside then you can achieve the same thing with `@Output` decorator inside of  your `header component`. Since you didn't provide enough code for me to show you a working solution, I will show you both examples and explain what we did there:

**Shared service approach (Best approach if your header component is not inside menu component)**

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { MySharedService } from 'XXXXXXXX';
import { MenuComponent } from 'XXXXXXXX';
import { HeaderComponent} from 'XXXXXXXX';
...
@NgModule({
     ...
     declarations: [
         MenuComponent,
         HeaderComponent,
     ],
     ...
     providers: [
         ...
         MySharedService,
     ]
})
```

**my_shared_service.service.ts**

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * App service with shared data on global scope of the app
 */
@Injectable()
export class MySharedService {
   /**
    * Currently selected item
    * from header component
    */
    private itemSelected: any = null;

    constructor() {}

    /**
    * Setter for selected item
    */
    public setItem(item: any): void {
        this.itemSelected = item;
    }
}
```

And finally this is how your components can use the `MySharedService`:

**header.component.ts**

```
import { MySharedService } from 'XXXXXXX';
...
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
     ...
     constructor(private _mySharedService: MySharedService) { }

     itemSelected(e: any) {
         this._mySharedService.setItem(e.target.value);
     }
     ...
}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<div class="select-style">
    <select name="roles" (change)="itemSelected($event)">
      <option value="" disabled selected> Role </option>
      <option value="admin">Administrator</option>
      <option value="user">Employee</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**menu.component.ts**

```
import { MySharedService } from 'XXXXXXX';
...
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
     ...
     constructor(private _mySharedService: MySharedService) { }
     ...
}
```

**menu.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="_mySharedService.item">
    Header component has a selected item, show this content.
</div>
```

In case your `menu component` contains `header component` inside of it, then you can do `Output` the value each time it changes the value and your `MenuComponent` can listen for these changes and do certain tasks depending on the received result:

**@Output approach (if menu component contains header component)**

**header.component.ts**

```
import { ..., EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
...
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
     ...
     @Output() onChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
     ...
     itemSelected(e: any) {
         this.onChange.emit(e.target.value);
     }
     ...
}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<div class="select-style">
    <select name="roles" (change)="itemSelected($event)">
      <option value="" disabled selected> Role </option>
      <option value="admin">Administrator</option>
      <option value="user">Employee</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**menu.component.html**

```
...
<ca-header (onChange)="itemChanged($event)"></ca-header>
...
<div *ngIf="_item">
    Header component has a selected item, show this content.
</div>
```

**menu.component.ts**

```
...
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
     ...
     private _item: any;
     ...
     itemChanged(value: any) {
         this._item = value;
     }
     ...
}
```