# Angular5 - How go back without lose data?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-routing

I'm using Angular5 and i can't go back in the browser without losing data. I mean, that the previous component, could be loaded with their data again.

Example:

In my component:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mant-cert-certificacion',
  templateUrl: './mant-cert-certificacion.component.html',
  styles: []
})

export class MantCertCertificacionComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private location: Location) {
  }
goBack() {
    this.location.back();
    console.log( 'goBack()...' );
  }
}
```

mant-cert-certificacion.component.html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="goBack()">
            <- Back
</a>
```

This component, it's called from my router module. When i click on the "go back" button, i wish to display the previous component with their data loaded.

My route module:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'xxxx', children: [
    { path: '', component: XComponent},
  ]},
  { path: 'yyyy', children: [
    { path: 'contractdetail/', component: MantCertCertificacionComponent}
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MantenedoresCertRoutingModule { }
```

Some idea?

This previous component would be "XComponent". The content of the information (attributes or variables) does not matter. I only want to load their data please.

Thanks!

Comment: In "XComponent", how did you load data at first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to persist during navigation you go for

1. `LocalStorage`
2. `sessionStorage`
3. `Services`

`localStorage` and `sessionStorage` accomplish the exact same thing and have the same API, but with `sessionStorage` the data is persisted only until the window or tab is closed, while with `localStorage` the data is persisted until the user manually clears the browser cache or until your web app clears the data.

I would suggest you to go for **[`@ngx-pwa/local-storage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage)** Async local storage for Angular

## For Angular 5:

```
npm install @ngx-pwa/local-storage@5
```

**Register it in your RootModule**

```
import { LocalStorageModule } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LocalStorageModule,
    ...
  ]
```

**Inject and use it**

```
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@Injectable()
export class YourService {

  constructor(protected localStorage: LocalStorage) {}

}
```

**Usage**

```
let user: User = { firstName: 'Henri', lastName: 'Bergson' };

this.localStorage.setItem('user', user).subscribe(() => {});
```

**Services**
Create a Service and Register it with an Angular module.

> why? If you want an instance of a dependency to be shared globally and
>   share `state` across the application you should configure it on the
>   `NgModule.`

**[`Sharing Data with BehaviorSubject`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50609666/5695162)**

Answer (score -5):

Angular preserves route details in its history.

```
window.history.back();
```

This should work.