# How to share data between two component?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular 4,im not able to communicate with component.I have sidenav component and I want to share values sidebar to main component.
Thanks.

Comment: Please share you code and what you're trying to attempt, what is not working and error messages.

Comment: [Angular Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I share data between components in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sidenav.component.ts
passData:any

sidenav.component.html
//Call your main component & share passData property
<app-component [passData]="passData"></app-component>

main.component.ts
@ViewChild(passData) passData: SidenavComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways. For example:

```
- @Output/@Input
- Service
```

In fact, there's even a whole section in Angular docs devoted to it:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service and add it to providers at app level (root) this way the service will be available to inject to all the component and any change on this service will be persist.

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalSharedService {
  public data:any;
}
```

app.module

```
@NgModule({
  ....
  providers: [GlobalSharedService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> In  Angular 6 you can add the service to proviers at the app.module level like this

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GlobalSharedService {
   public data:any;
  }
```

> All service added at the app.module the created once that why the persist  there state and called **singleton service**