# how to pass the input value to another component when clicked in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

**component1.html**

```
<input type="text" value="some text">
<button>next</button>
```

**anotherComponent.html**

```
<input type="text">//value of component1 should be shown here when the button is clicked.
```

There are two independent components here.

My question is how to pass value of component1 to anotherComponent when the button is clicked.

Comment: are they `child` & `parent` components ? or they both are independent ? Be more specific and let us know what have you tried till now. You can get it on google pretty easily

Comment: both are independent components. I tried using decorator @input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I share data between components in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share data between 2 independent components. @Input and @Output method can be used. Please check for the correct syntax to be used. Please refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZzE5o0VsMo .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)