# How to connect from one component to other in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 different component, which is of different modules too.
now i am saving data in one component, that saved data must be fetched to the other component.
How can i fetch data from component to component, Please help.

First component:

```
saveSidebar() {
    let params = { userGuID: this.uID, MenuIds: this.selectedMenuIds.toString() }
    console.log(params);
    this._Service.addUserMenu(params).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.Header.Success) {

      }
    })
  }
```

Here the saved data must go to `menu component` which is in different component

Comment: simply define a shared service, send data to it and get from it. see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: You can use `share service` , or you can implement the `redux`  for sharing data or called state management. this will make you application more scalable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I share data between components in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a service which is imported in both components and its data shared. So then you can update the service from the first component, then create an event listener on the other component which listens to the changes of the service and updates the ui/data accordingly.

Comment: i have tried in this way only, but i am not able to get data as i need

Comment: @Bhrungarajni can you share the code you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

For parent-child communication you can use @input() @output();
For others, you can use services, register the service in parent module or root module, to learn more please visit below link.
https://blog.nrwl.io/essential-angular-dependency-injection-a6b9dcca1761

Answer (score 0):

If multiple modules are using the same variable data, then it is better create a service in the app-root level, modify and access its variables wherever required in your project, a sample code of service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';        

      @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
      })
      export class UserinfoService {
        public userName : string = 'username'
      }
```

making the service injectable in the root level is necessary in order to access it all over the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subjects or behavioral subjects. As change in one component will automatically get reflected in other component using subjects.