# How do I pass data from one component to another using the Router in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I would like to know how to pass data between two components using the Router. The image below is a screenshot of the view of my component.

[image]

When I click the button **View report** I need to "call" another component with the data for each report.

The following lines of code are the button **View report** that calls the method `viewFuelReport()`; it opens the other component with the data in a new tab.

```js
<button type="button" (click)="viewFuelReport()" class="btn btn-success">
     View report
</button>
```

```js
viewFuelReport(){
    this.router.navigate([]).then(result => {
      window.open("/pages/view-report", "_blank");
    });
  }
```

How do I pass data from one component to another using the Router in Angular?

Comment: You can do it in many ways like using service, query params , route data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I share data between components in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to share data from a child component to a parent component, you can use `@Output()` and `EventEmitter<>`.

Or if you are trying to share data between two unrelated components, you can use `BehaviorSubject()` via a `Service`; that also works for sharing data between parent and child components.

### Child to parent: Sharing data using `@Output()` and `EventEmitter<>`.

#### parent.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-parent',
 template: `
 Message: {{ message }}
  <app-child (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"></app-child>
  `,
 styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent{
 constructor(){}

 message: string;

 receiveMessage($event){
  this.message = $event
 }
}
```

#### child.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-child',
 template: `
  <button (click)="sendMessage()">Send message</button>
  `,
 styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent{
 message: string = "Hola, Mundo!";

 @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

 constructor(){}

 sendMessage(){
  this.messageEvent.emit(this.message);
 }
}
```

### Unrelated components: Sharing data via a Service

#### data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService{
 private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('Original 
 message.');

 currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

 changeMessage(message: string){
  this.messageSource.next(message)
 }
}
```

#### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { DataService } from 
'src/app/shared/services/data.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-home',
 template: `
  {{ message }}
  `,
 styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
 message: string;

 constructor(private dataService: DataService){}

 ngOnInit(){
  this.dataService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => 
  this.message = message)
 }
}
```

#### about.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { DataService } from 
'src/app/shared/services/data.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-about',
 template: `
  {{ message }}
  <button (click)="newMessage()">New message</button>
  `,
 styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit{
 message: string;

 constructor(private dataService: DataService){}

 ngOnInit(){
  this.dataService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => 
  this.message = message)
  }

 newMessage(){
  this.dataService.changeMessage('Hello from the About 
  component!')
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `window.open` looks absolutely awful. Use `this.router.navigate(['/heroes']);`.

So if I understand correctly you have a list of items and when you click on one of the items, the details page of that item should open?

Best practice is to allow the detail route to have a property to set. the Angular [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router) page is very complete. It shows that you should use `:id` - `{ path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }`. When you open the detail page, you get the id variable and then get the data for it.