# Cross component communication with angular 2+ (any child to any parent)

Tags: angular, events, event-handling, hierarchy, broadcast

I have been working on web application in Angular 2+. and i have following situation

```
component A
  |
  component B
    |
    component C
      |
      component D   //click on button -> call apis and return value to component A's variable
```

In `component D` there is button if user click on that we need to call rest API and that API's result should be show in `component A`.

Business case : Consider that `component A` is your top header which contain point count and form `component D` user do some task and based on that task i need to increment that points.

I can achieve this functionality with broadcast service in angular `Subject<BroadcastEvent>` (after api return value create broadcast and in component A i am listing that event ) but i am not sure that if there is a better way to do this stuff.
Or i can't use same service in both component because I need to assign value in variable as well as in show in DOM. If i need only DOM element to be updated than service can resolve my problem but i also need in components variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I share data between components in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular-2)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild
Check that. I think it's useful for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it makes sense to make a service keep the number of points. That service is then injected into component D to call service.addPoints().
That service is also injected into component A to call service.getPoints().

componentA.component.ts:

```
export class componentA  {

constructor(public myService: MyService){}

}
```

componentA.component.html:

```
{{myService.getPoints()}}
```

componentD.component.ts:

```
export class componentD  {

constructor(public myService: MyService){}

}
```

componentD.component.html:

```
<button (click)="{{myService.addPoints()"></button>
```

myService.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
public points: number;

public getPoints(){
  return this.points;
}

public addPoints(){
  this.points = this.points +1;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but in that case how component A's will know that service.getPoints() method when to call ?

Comment: Put it in the template of component A. You will see angular makes sure the current points are displayed.

Comment: agreed with two way binding DOM element will update but how about componet A variable ? it will not reflect new value.

Comment: I see we are talking about 2 differnt things, I´ll add code. :)

Comment: {{myService.getPoints()}} in component A make sense.But i have another scenario i need to call function in component A after addPoints() from is called.is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it´s possible. Every function in myService is available in the components where you injected myService.

Answer (score 1):

if you call your api in a method of ComponentB you can use

> @viewchild(ComponentA)ComponentA:ComponentA

in your ComponentB and Assignment result api from ComponentB to variable or array of ComponentA.
for example You define a array in ComponentA and:

> ComponentA

```
export class componentA { 
    points = [];
}
```

> ComponentB

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ComponentA } from '{{ComponentA_PATH}}/ComponentA';

export class ComponentB { 
    @viewchild(ComponentA) componentARef: ComponentA;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient)

    GetPoints() {
    this.httpClient.get(your url).subscribe(
      result=>{
        componentARef.points.push(result);
              }
               }
}
```

but this way is not bestway you should create a sevice and pass data bettween components like the above answer but this is also a way i hope i have been able to help.